# Put a foreach into array / php

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, foreach

With my symfony command, I want to display an array of multiple data. How to fill the fields of my table in an automatic way as I tried to do in my example?

```
$table = new Table($output);
 $table->setHeaders(array('ID', 'Date'))
       ->setRows(array(
                 foreach ($productsCursor as $product) {
                      array($product->getId(), $product->getCreated()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')),
                 }
         ));
            $table->render();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "array of multiple data"? Can you give an example of that data?

Comment: You can't put function in array, follow the answer of @DanyalSandeelo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the loop outside the declaration and then use it inside like this:

```
$dataArray= array()
foreach ($productsCursor as $product) {
   $dataArray[] =   array($product->getId(), $product->getCreated()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
}
```

and then you can set it as:

```
$table = new Table($output);
$table->setHeaders(array('ID', 'Date'))->setRows($dataArray);
$table->render();
```

Comment: doesnt work because whe don't have the ";" at the end of each line for $dataArray[]